# Создание полноценного статичного веб сайта на node.js с более лаконичным и правильным кодом

Tags: веб-программирование, node.js, express, static

Доброго времени суток, я относительно недавно закончил обучение FrontEnd разработке, ну и под конец понял, что мне этого безумно мало и при выборе технологии для BackEnd сам не помню как остановился на node.js... И вот захотелось в качестве первого мини-проекта сделать статичный сайт, пока что без изысков, разобрался с тем, что в браузер стили, картинки,скрипты, сам html и т.п. попадают каждый через свой отдельный запрос так сказать... ну и написал код, который все эти запросы обрабатывает, но не успел я и 30 строк написать, стало ясно, что код оооооочень неуклюжий и с огромным количеством повторений при написании респонса сервера...

Мой вопрос такой:"Можно ли как-то упаковать запросы на составляющие веб страницы, чтобы это не требовало так много повторяющегося кода?"
(я пока пишу все на чистом js, но если кто знает, как это можно решить через express или другой надежный фреймворк, то пишите пожалуйстя)

Заранее всем спасибо)))))))))))

```
const http = require("http");
const port = 3000,
css = `h1{color: red; font-family: Verdana; text-align: center; 
background-color: #121212;}`,
    html = `<!doctype>
                <html>
                <head>
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="serverus_snape2.css"><br/>  
                    <script src="serverus_snape2.js"></script>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <h1>Dumbledore!</h1>
                    <button id="q">press this</button>
                </body>
                </html>`,
    js = `let button = document.getElementById("q");
    button.addEventListener("click", event => alert("node.js is awesome!"));`;

http.createServer((req,resp) => {
console.log(req.url);
console.log(req.method);
console.log(req.headers);



// я это делал для упражнения, потому и над этим комментарием такой бардак
// мой вопрос относится к тому коду, что ниже(следовало наверное использовать
//if,  но почему-то захотелось попробовать switch )))



switch(req.url){
case "/":
resp.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type":"text/html"});

resp.end("Snape...Snape...Serverus Snape..."+ html);

case'/serverus_snape2.js':
resp.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type":"text/javascript"});

resp.end(js);

case'/serverus_snape2.css':
resp.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type":"text/css"});

resp.end(css);

default:
resp.writeHead(404,{"Content-Type":"text/plain"});

resp.end("404! file not found");
}

}).listen(port, () => {

console.log("server working on port " + port);

});
```

Comment: Посмотрите тут http://www.clock.co.uk/blog/a-simple-website-in-node-js-2016-edition и исходники https://github.com/bengourley/basic-express-site-2016

Comment: Есть же книжка "Веб-разработка с применением Node и Express", есть скринкаст Когана на learn.javascript.ru, сделанный по этой же книжке (когда ещё не было её перевода). И там, и там всё объясняется - лучше не бывает. А как отдать статичный файл с "чистого Node" (что чиста для пользы полезно попробовать, конечно) - это можно увидеть в разделе AJAX и COMET указанного выше сайтика (главного учебного сайтика про javascript на русском языке).